# is there any function to get soap function name list (not list of prototypes) in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to get the list of function names.

I tried this code

```
$functions = $soapClient->__getFunctions();
```

but it returns the list of prototypes containing return_type `function_name(params)`.

But I just need list of `function_name`.

Comment: __getTypes() give you information about the structure of your parameters (both in & out, for instance, Credit is a complex type with a username & password) are, __getFunctions() shows you which function to call.

Comment: http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/PHP-SOAP-Client-Function-List.html